# merge nodes with the same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an Treenode which might have same keys..I need to merge them so that there are no duplicate folders..

```
ParentObj = [{
"data": {
    "resTitle": "-JANAF Thermochemical Tables - SRD 13"
},
"children": [{
    "data": {
        "filePath": "borides"
    },
    "children": [{
        "data": {
            "filePath": "titanium"
        },
        "children": [{
            "data": {
                "filePath": "srd13_B-102.json"
            },
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "data": {
        "filePath": "borides"
    },
    "children": [{
        "data": {
            "filePath": "titanium"
        },
        "children": [{
            "data": {
                "filePath": "srd13_B-103.json"
            },
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}]
}]
```

I need to merge borides so that titanium and zirconium are under borides.
borides will be parent for titanium and zirconium.

structure would be

borides -

- titanium - B-102.json
- zirconium - B103.json

here is the code I have..

```
 var arr = JSON.stringify(parentObj);
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log("inside i loop");

  var found = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
    console.log("inside i loop");
    if (result[j].children.filePath == arr[i].children.filePath) {
      found = true;
      result[j].nodes = result[j].nodes.concat(arr[i].nodes);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    result.push(arr[i]);

  }
}
```

I appreciate your help

Update: if I have same titanium folder in 2nd level, folder is getting repeated (updated JSON)..please advise how to resolve this..

Comment: NB: why `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parentObj))`?

Comment: parentObj is a treenode.. so I am trying to convert into string and then to array

Comment: Is it only the top level that might have duplicates?

Comment: The way you specified `ParentObj` (with capital first letter: the first reason for malfunctioning code), it *is already* an array.

Comment: for now.. only top level have duplicates

Comment: my intention was to convert it to array

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parentObj))` is redundant. You turn it into a string, and then immediately reverse the process by parsing it back into a variable. You will get out exactly what you put in, it's pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common and efficient approach is create a hashmap object using the common property values as keys and full objects as the value

Then it is a simple lookup to see if that key already exists or not. If it does, merge the current with the one in hashmap. Then finlly get merged results from the hashmap

```js
const tmp ={}

ParentObj.children.forEach((o) => {
  const path = o.data.filePath;
  if (tmp[path]) {
    tmp[path].children = tmp[path].children || [];// in case no children property or array exists
    tmp[path].children.push(...o.children)
  } else {
    tmp[path] = o;
  }
  
});

ParentObj.children = Object.values(tmp);
console.log(ParentObj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
  const ParentObj = {
    "data": {
      "resTitle": "-JANAF Thermochemical Tables - SRD 13"
    },
    "children": [{
      "data": {
        "filePath": "borides"
      },
      "children": [{
        "data": {
          "filePath": "titanium"
        },
        "children": [{
          "data": {
            "filePath": "srd13_B-102.json"
          },
          "children": []
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "data": {
        "filePath": "borides"
      },
      "children": [{
        "data": {
          "filePath": "zirconium"
        },
        "children": [{
          "data": {
            "filePath": "srd13_B-103.json"
          },
          "children": []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You made my day!!! Thank you so much.. I will revert back if there are any issues.. so far working good..

Comment: Is there any alternative for Object.values(tmp), I am using typescript and getting an error " error TS2339: Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.".. I tried to use ES2017 in tsconfig.json.. but still getting the error

Comment: can use a `for in` loop. `const arr=[]; for(let key in tmp){arr.push(tmp[key])}`

Comment: hello charlie, sorry.. second level also has duplicates..borides - titanium - 102.json, borides - titanium - 103.json

Comment: how can I reuse your script to check for duplicates in multiple levels?

Comment: Hello charlie.. can you please update your answer if there are duplicates in the second level too?